# qpdf unable to output to stdout

Tags: pdf, qpdf

I am trying to write qpdf output to stdout.

```
qpdf --empty --pages 1.pdf 1 2.pdf 2 -- /dev/stdout
```

But it says `open /dev/stdout: Permission denied`.

Why qpdf can not write the output to stdout? Does it require random access in the output file to successfully write the output? Thanks.

Comment: pdftk can write output to stdout. I don't see a reason why qpdf can not do so.

Comment: `/dev/stdout` is not of what? The last sentence was not complete. I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: OK.      `-`   works. -----